# strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1

Tags: php, magento2

I'm having a problem with a Magento Extension.

Error:
Deprecated Functionality: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in Setup/ChangeMethodsFormat.php on line 40

Line 40 is: `if (strpos($oldMethods, "\n") === false) {`

function is:

```
     $oldMethods = $rule->getMethods();
        if (strpos($oldMethods, "\n") === false) {
            continue;
        }
```

can somebody help me?

PHP Version: 8.1.7

Comment: `$rule->getMethods()` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `$oldMethods` is null. So you could check for that:

```
if ($oldMethods !== null || strpos($oldMethods, "\n") === false){
continue;
}
```

I assume that or is the correct operator.

Comment: is correct. is NOT null isn't

Answer (score -3):

I solved this with using:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED );
```

before:

```
        if (strpos($oldMethods, "\n") === false){
        continue;
        }
```

This will switch off the Depracted warning. I know it's not te best way but it's working.

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: stripos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/sanasafinaz/vendor/magento/module-price-permissions/Observer/AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBeforeObserver.php on line 125

Comment: what about this error?

Comment: you have to check this file: AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBeforeObserver.php on line 125

Comment: thank you for your effort, but this error was  comming due to custom module

Comment: Yes I see it's from module-price-permissions.

Login to your server with a FTP Programm like Filezilla or use your weblogin and go to this directory: 
sanasafinaz/vendor/magento/module-price-permissions/Observer/

Download the FIle: AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBeforeObserver.php

Open it with a Programm like Notepad++ and check what's in the line 125